# Shader issues when creating projection using CreateOrthographicOffCenter instead of CreateOrthographic

Tags: xna, shaders, projection

**Pre.** Having these matrix transformations:

```cs
var scale = Matrix.CreateScale(50f);
var eye = new Vector3(0, 0, 10.0f);
var view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(eye, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
var projection = scale * Matrix.CreateOrthographic(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 1.0f, 1000f);
var rotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(-MathHelper.PiOver2)*Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.PiOver2);
```

and then for each mesh producing “world” like this:

```cs
var localWorld = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * rotation;
```

and then applying these parameters to the effect:

```cs
effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(localWorld);
effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(view);
effect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(projection);
effect.Parameters["Bones"].SetValue(boneTransforms);
effect.Parameters["WorldInverseTranspose"].SetValue(Matrix.Transpose(Matrix.Invert(localWorld)));
```

I’m getting nice model like this:

[image: Kangaroo using CreateOrthographic]

**Post.** But after I changed **CreateOrthographic** to **CreateOrthographicOffCenter** like this:

```cs
var projection = scale * Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(-GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2f, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2f, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2f, -GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2f, 1.0f, 1000f);
var rotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(-MathHelper.PiOver2);
```

I’ve got this:

[image: Kangaroo using CreateOrthographicOffCenter]

Can someone give me a hint what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You `CreateOrthographic` and `CreateOrthographicOffCenter` calls are equivalent, but the rotations applied aren't the same.

Comment: @r2d2rigo I know. But that doesn’t change anything. Without rotation modification model will stay dark. But except for that, it will be also facing down.

Answer (score 1):

Found an error.

```cs
Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(-GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2f, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2f, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2f, -GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2f, 1.0f, 1000f);
```

That’s not the same as

```cs
 Matrix.CreateOrthographic(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 1.0f, 1000f);
```

CreateOrthographicOffCenter sets **M11** as *2f / (right - left)* and so we’re getting value equal to **GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width**, but **M22** is set as *2f / (top - bottom)* resulting in height equal to **-GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height**

Thus, correct setup for the **CreateOrthographicOffCenter** is

```cs
Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(-GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2f, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2f, -GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2f, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2f, 1.0f, 1000f);
```